# Incorporate existing project into existing git repo

Tags: git, github, git-svn

Here's the scenario:

My company is updating a website for one of our clients. Until recently we would develop on a local machine and then commit our changes on their SVN account. In order to access their SVN account we needed to be connected to their VPN. My boss told me the client gets upset if I commit changes while a project is still in progress as they used a "waterfall" development model. Therefore, I currently have a few dozen files that have uncommitted changes.

I don't know much about SVN or "waterfall" development but that doesn't matter because last week, while my company was shut down for the holidays, they ditched their VPN as well as their SVN account and switched over to gitHub and an agile development model. Now I can't commit my changes to their project's SVN account because neither it nor the VPN exist anymore.

My question is, once I get access to their gitHub account and I clone a repo of the project, how can I incorporate my existing changes? Do I just need to remember each of the several dozen files I worked on and manually copy them over to the repo and commit? That seems like a pain. Is there an alternate way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While there are tools to convert an SVN repo to git repo, I'm sure there are no tools for cross-SCM merges. This just wouldn't make sense since it is unlikely that some one will be developing a project in two different repositories.

One thing you can do is to clone git repo and run `git diff` on modified files outside the repository (ones you need to import). Then you'll see the diff and will be able to resolve conflicts. Add and push. Either way it is better, simplier and more convenient to resolve such a delicate issue manually.

Comment: Thanks Zloj. Manual it is then.